# github-cli unknown command "run" for "gh workflow"

Tags: github-cli

I have started using github actions recently and i wanted to use the github-cli for actions and I have been following a tutorial on how to manually run a workflow: https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_workflow_run

Well, on my machine I get the following:

```
.github/workflows (git)-[windows_workflow] % gh workflow run    
unknown command "run" for "gh workflow"

Usage:  gh workflow <command> [flags]

Available commands:
```

Ideas? I'm following the API and I have a recent version of github-cli:

```
gh version 1.8.1 (2021-04-03)
https://github.com/cli/cli/releases/tag/v1.8.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gh workflow` has been added in [gh v1.9.0](https://github.com/cli/cli/releases/tag/v1.9.0), and you are using v1.8.1.

Comment: Thank you. While I no longer need this, I'm sure this information would be useful to ppl.