# unknown command "clone" for "gh"

Tags: github-cli

I have started using github-cli on two machines (laptop and desktop).

i logged in useing `gh` and it works.

if u use

`gh clone https://github.com/ repo-link /code.git`

i get this error:

`unknown command "clone" for "gh"`

i installed it like so:

https://www.techiediaries.com/install-github-cli-ubuntu-20/

i searched the web and read here that not helped me:

[github-cli unknown command "run" for "gh workflow"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67220552/github-cli-unknown-command-run-for-gh-workflow)

Comment: Does https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_repo_clone help? There is no command `clone` on its own

Comment: Also, GitHub CLI is not a replacement for `git`.

Comment: `gh repo clone ` ask me for username / password. bot machines has fresh ubunto installed. it works at laptop but not at desktop. strange

Comment: laptop works lik so. desktop produce this error now. so my conclusion. it normally working

Comment: @SL5net https://github.com/cli/cli/issues/1326

Comment: If you assume that this is an error in the software, why not post an issue in their bug tracker?